# What are the errors in the bubble sort algorithm code?

Tags: python

#I just now started coding and tried the bubble sort algorithm for practice , but the first and last value does get get swapped.#

```
    def bubble_sort(arr): 
        n = len(arr)

        for i in range(n - 1):
            for j in range(0, n - i - 1):
                if arr[j] > arr[j + 1]:
                    arr[j], arr[j + 1] = arr[j + 1], arr[j]
            else:
                return None

    lst = []
    r = int(input("Enter number of elements you want in array:"))
    for k in range(1, r + 1):
        x = int(input("Enter value:"))
        lst.append(x)

    print("The given array :", lst)
    print("The sorted array :", bubble_sort(lst))
```

Output:

```
    Enter number of elements you want in array:6
    Enter value:55
    Enter value:12
    Enter value:43
    Enter value:87
    Enter value:76
    Enter value:33
    [55,12,43,76,87,33]
```

#The final two statements doesn't execute either, can someone find the error in the code and explain #

Answer (score 0):

You are returning None after the loop is completing.

In python you can write an `else` with `for` loop. You can read from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/using-else-conditional-statement-with-for-loop-in-python/

So, it is not a syntax error but as per your logic, after the for loop completes it is just returning `None`.

Following code is giving the answer

```py
def bubble_sort(arr): 
    n = len(arr)

    for i in range(n - 1):
        for j in range(0, n - i - 1):
            if arr[j] > arr[j + 1]:
                arr[j], arr[j + 1] = arr[j + 1], arr[j]
    return arr

lst = []
r = int(input("Enter number of elements you want in array:"))
for k in range(1, r + 1):
    x = int(input("Enter value:"))
    lst.append(x)

print("The given array :", lst)
print("The sorted array :", bubble_sort(last))
```

Comment: So since the loop has a return none statement , it didn't give the output I wanted..wow thank you for ur help